# C++11 sleep_ functions having odd behaviour

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

[Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) it says that `sleep_for` "Blocks the execution of the current thread for *at least* the specified sleep_duration."

[Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until) it says that `sleep_until` "Blocks the execution of the current thread *until specified* sleep_time *has been reached*."

So with this in mind I was simply doing my thing, until I noticed that my code was sleeping a lot shorter than the specified time. To make sure it was the sleep_ code being odd instead off me making dumb code again, I created this online example: https://ideone.com/9a9MrC
(code block below the edit line) When running the online example, it does exactly what it should be doing, but running the exact same code sample on my machine gives me this output: [Output on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/0Pc51eAY)

Now I'm truly confused and wondering what the *bleep* is going wrong on my machine. I'm using Code::Blocks as IDE on a Win7 x64 machine in combination with [This](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/4.8.2/threads-posix/seh/) toolchain containing GCC 4.8.2.

*I have tried [This](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/gcc-4.8-release/) toolchain before the current one, but this one with GCC 4.8.0 strangely enough wasn't even able to compile the example code.

What could create this weird behaviour? My machine? Windows? GCC? Something else in the toolchain?

p.s. The example also works as it should on [Here](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php), which states that it uses GCC version 4.7.2

p.p.s. using `#include <windows.h>` and `Sleep( 1 );` also sleeps a lot shorter than the specified 1 millisecond on my machine.

EDIT: code from example:

```
#include <iostream>         // std::cout, std::fixed
#include <iomanip>          // std::setprecision
//#include <string>           // std::string
#include <chrono> // C++11  // std::chrono::steady_clock
#include <thread> // C++11  // std::this_thread

std::chrono::steady_clock timer;
auto startTime = timer.now();
auto endTime = timer.now();
auto sleepUntilTime = timer.now();

int main() {

for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i ) {
    startTime = timer.now();
    sleepUntilTime = startTime + std::chrono::nanoseconds( 1000000 );
    std::this_thread::sleep_until( sleepUntilTime );
    endTime = timer.now();
    std::cout << "Start time: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>( startTime.time_since_epoch() ).count() << "\n";
    std::cout << "End   time: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>( endTime.time_since_epoch() ).count() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Sleep till: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>( sleepUntilTime.time_since_epoch() ).count() << "\n";

    std::cout << "It took: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>( endTime - startTime ).count() << " nanoseconds. \n";
    std::streamsize prec = std::cout.precision();
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(9);
    std::cout << "It took: " << ( (float) std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>( endTime - startTime ).count() / 1000000 ) << " milliseconds. \n";
    std::cout << std::setprecision( prec );
}
std::cout << "\n\n";
for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i ) {
    startTime = timer.now();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::nanoseconds( 1000000 ) );
    endTime = timer.now();
    std::cout << "Start time: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>( startTime.time_since_epoch() ).count() << "\n";
    std::cout << "End   time: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>( endTime.time_since_epoch() ).count() << "\n";

    std::cout << "It took: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>( endTime - startTime ).count() << " nanoseconds. \n";
    std::streamsize prec = std::cout.precision();
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(9);
    std::cout << "It took: " << ( (float) std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>( endTime - startTime ).count() / 1000000 ) << " milliseconds. \n";
    std::cout << std::setprecision( prec );
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please include code blocks in the question instead of links.

Comment: The granularity of Sleep() is too high to handle a 1ms timeout and it's probably being rounded down to 0.  Sleeping for 5 seconds is fine, sleeping for 1ms is an inappropriate use of Sleep().

Comment: [`steady_clock` is broken on Windows](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/753115/). Try `high_resolution_clock` or `system_clock` instead.

Comment: @Manu343726 Edited in the code from the example.

Comment: @Martin James I'm not really interested in using the specific windows sleep variant, but since the parameter wants an amount in milliseconds, I thought I would try it, to see if that would actually sleep for the minimum specified milliseconds.

Comment: @Casey In your link I'm seeing VC++, but I'm using GCC, which makes me wonder whether or not that link is relevant. Besides that, the last comment in your link states that this is now fixed.

Comment: @ParvusM I'm also using GCC on Windows, and the program behaves as expected using either `high_resolution_clock` or `system_clock`, and as you observe with `steady_clock`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your machine, it is your assumptions that are wrong.

Sleeping is a very system-dependent and unreliable thing. Generally, on most operating systems, you have a more-or-less-guarantee that a call to sleep will delay execution for *at least* the time you ask for. The C++ thread library necessarily uses the facilities provided by the operating system, hence the wording in the C++ standard that you quoted.

You will have noted the wording *"more-or-less-guarantee"* in the above paragraph. First of all, the way sleeping works is not what you might think. It generally does not block until a timer fires and then resumes execution. Instead, it merely marks the thread as "not ready", and additionally does something so this can be undone later (what exactly this is isn't defined, it might be setting a timer or something else).
When the time is up, the operating system will set the thread to "ready to run" again. This doesn't mean it will run, it only means it is a candidate to run, whenever the OS can be bothered and whenever a CPU core is free (and nobobdy with higher priority wants it).

On traditional non-tickless operating systems, this will mean that the thread will *probably* (or more precisely, *maybe*) run at the next scheduler tick. That is, if CPU is available at all. On more modern operating systems (Linux 3.x or Windows 8) which are "tickless", you're a bit closer to reality, but you still do not have any hard guarantees.

Further, under Unix-like systems, `sleep` may be interrupted by a signal and may actually wait less than the specified time. Also, under Windows, the interval at which the scheduler runs is configurable, and to make it worse, different Windows versions behave differently [[1]](http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/02/sleep-variation-investigated/) [[2]](http://cbloomrants.blogspot.de/2013/03/03-19-13-windows-sleep-variation.html) in respect of whether they round the sleep time up or down.
Your system (Windows 7) rounds *down*, so indeed yes, you may actually wait less than what you expected.

### tl;dr

Sleep is unreliable and only a very rough "hint" (not a requirement) that you wish to pass control back to the operating system for *some time*.

Comment: Sleep() is reliable if the interval is not inappropriately short.  As for the thread not being set running when it becomes ready, that is little different than the behaviour of any other system call that changes the set of ready threads.  You may as well say that any such system call is 'unreliable'.

Comment: C++11 §30.2.4 guarantees that conforming implementations of `this_thread::sleep_for` and `this_thread::sleep_until` will sleep for at least as long as specified.

Comment: @MartinJames: It depends on what you define as being "reliable". Waiting on a sync primitive will (under Windows) give the thread a priority boost, which more or less guarantees (under normal conditions) that it will run. At least, it will run as soon as possible. Sleep will run _eventually_, which is very different. Certainly, if the interval is long enough, then scheduler granularity will technically not matter (for example, if you sleep for 10 seconds, it doesn't really matter if you sleep 15ms too long). But "reliable" in a sense that you get exactly what you ask for, no.

Comment: @Casey: That means that a _truly_ conforming implementation would have to check how long the sleep lasted (since it is possible to wait _less_ under any OS), which is trivial under Unix since the function returns the actual duration, but a real pain under Windows. Which makes me doubt that any real implementation is indeed conforming (under Windows). Or, the implementation could of course just add a few milliseconds to the value that you request, and always wait longer... that would suck big time but it would be conforming :)

Comment: @Damon Your post and links are very helpful and it is somewhat a relief to know that nothing is actually broken on my end. However, I find it a bit peculiar that no sort of (compiler) warning is given anywhere that the *at least* part might not be true on all platforms.
On a related note: While the granularity of anything below 1ms is considered to be too low, it will run and give random results ranging from 400ns up to <5μs. (on my machine... your results may vary)